# SQL query returning results and need to show as comma separated

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following query which works well.

```
select     distinct d_invoice.*,
           center.centerid 
from       d_invoice
inner join center 
on         center.centerid = d_invoice._center
```

Now the above query gives me the `dr_id` which is the PK of the table `d_invoice`

With the below query from a different table, it gives me the `item_id`, as one `dr_id` can have multiple items:

```
select item_id 
from   d_invoice_items 
where  dr_id = 10
```

I want to join both queries so I can create a new column called as `items` and it will list down all the `item_id` in the comma separated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH` something like:

```
select distinct d.*,
    c.centerid,
    stuff((
            select ',' + item_id
            from d_invoice_items i
            where i.dr_id = d.dr_id
            for xml path('')
            ), 1, 1, '') as items
from d_invoice d
inner join center c on c.centerid = d._center;
```

Comment: the dr_id is the column in the d_invoice_items table and the dr_id is the pk of the d_invoice table - based upon is this correct code you pasted above